# MySQL adds broken comment script after each line

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Every time I try to create a table using MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE it adds "broken" comments at the end of the script.

Example:

I am trying to create a table called "user". This is what the table should look like:
[image: Table Example]

However when I click the apply button, the script generates incorrectly:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `userid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `record_status` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '',
  `createdby` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `createddate` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `updatedby` VARCHAR(75) NULL COMMENT '',
  `updateddate` DATETIME NULL COMMENT '',
  `username` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `password` VARCHAR(75) NULL COMMENT '',
  `firstname` VARCHAR(75) NULL COMMENT '',
  `lastname` VARCHAR(75) NULL COMMENT '',
  `email` VARCHAR(75) NULL COMMENT '',
  `facebook_userid` VARCHAR(75) NULL COMMENT '',
  `email_verified` VARCHAR(75) NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`, `username`)  COMMENT '');
```

The comment in this line should not be there, so the code should be:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`userid`, `username`));
```

and the code executes when I paste it into an editor and remove this comment. However I create massive databases daily. (Each with +- 15 tables). I can't keep doing this for each table as it is time consuming.

How can I disable this feature that adds the comments to the script?
I don't need them in my databases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug on MySQL Workbench `>=6.3.*` reported in these cases **[#76578](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76578)** and [**HERE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-4.html).

This is what `ALTER TABLE` do:

- It adds a `COMMENT ''` on every line of the SQL Script to apply:

[image]

I recommended you to downgrade your `MySQL Workbench` to `6.2.*` until they fix this.

Tested in `Ubuntu LTS 14.04` and `MySQL Workbench 6.3.4.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all occurence of `COMMENT ''`. Feel free to leave a comment under this [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77910). We're working on it to fix it, so stay tuned for upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to 6.2; 6.3 has the bug you describe.